# Python MRO and super() Isn't Behaving as Expected

Tags: python, super, method-resolution-order

With the following code below, the expected output of

```
Bottom2().method()
```

would be

```
Bottom2
Top
```

However, "Top" is missing. Why?

Reference: [Super Python (part 2)](https://lwn.net/Articles/892080/)

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.python_version()
'3.10.7'
>>> class Top:
...     def method(self):
...         print('Top')
...
>>>
>>> class Left(Top):
...     def method(self):
...         print('Left')
...         super().method()
...
>>> class Right(Top):
...     def method(self):
...         print('Right')
...         super().method()
...
>>> class Bottom(Left, Right):
...     def method(self):
...         print('Bottom')
...         super(Left, self).method()
...
>>> class Bottom2(Left, Right):
...     def method(self):
...         print('Bottom2')
...         super(Right, self).method
...
>>> Bottom().method()
Bottom
Right
Top
>>>
>>> Bottom.mro()
[<class '__main__.Bottom'>, <class '__main__.Left'>, <class '__main__.Right'>, <class '__main__.Top'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> Bottom2().method()
Bottom2
>>> Bottom2.mro()
[<class '__main__.Bottom2'>, <class '__main__.Left'>, <class '__main__.Right'>, <class '__main__.Top'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Comment: `super(Right, self).method` you want to call this, too, right?

Comment: Yes, but your question made me look at that line and realized that it was missing the () after method.

Answer (score 0):

See @Daraan's question. I forgot the () after .method. Added them and now the code works as expected.

```
class Bottom2(Left, Right):
    def method(self):
        print('Bottom2')
        super(Right, self).method # <========

>>> class Bottom2(Left, Right):
...     def method(self):
...         print('Bottom2')
...         super(Right, self).method()
...
>>> Bottom2().method()
Bottom2
Top
>>>
```